# Why does anime.js skip over certain delays when animating CSS properties?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, anime.js

I'm experimenting with anime.js to move around elements and animate CSS properties. I have found that when animating certain properties, such as `left` or `top`, anime.js overwrites or skips over to the last animation of this property.

For example, here is some code that I've been working on where I've seen this happening:

```
<style>

div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}

#square {
  left: 100px;
  top: 50px;
}
</style>

<div id="square"></div>

<script>
anime({
  targets: '#square',
  left: 300,
  delay: 2000
});

anime({
  targets: '#square',
  left: 700,
  delay: 4000
});
</script>
```

Instead of moving the square to the 300px position at 2 seconds, and then 700px position at 4 seconds, all I see is the square being moved to 700px after 4 seconds. It seems like the first 300px bit is **entirely ignored**. Why does this occur, and is there any workaround to this? Or should I structure the animation code differently to make sure this doesn't happen? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

After some experimentation, I found that the solution is somewhere in the anime.js documentation. I needed to use keyframes like so:

```
anime({
  targets: '#square',
  left: [
    {value: 300, delay: 2000},
    {value: 700, delay: 2000}
  ]
});
```

This ensures that one animation is not ignored, allowing the shape to be moved first to the 300px position and then to the 700px position, at 2s and 4s respectively.